# Linking one table with continuous dates to another non-continuous

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables, one with continuous daily dates/prices:

```
fs_perm_sec_id  date            p_price
KX8CBL-S-GB    2014-02-21      3.3515
KX8CBL-S-GB    2014-02-20      3.345
KX8CBL-S-GB    2014-02-19      3.3575
KX8CBL-S-GB    2014-02-18      3.297
```

and another with sporadic date entries:

```
fs_perm_sec_id  split_date  p_split_factor
KX8CBL-S-GB     1998-07-06  0.333333015
KX8CBL-S-GB     1991-02-04  0.970365703
KX8CBL-S-GB     1987-07-06  0.333333015
KX8CBL-S-GB     1985-05-03  0.983739793
```

I'd like to join them so that I have the daily date in the 1st column, then the date of the most recent split and split factor until a point where the daily date = the split date (1998-07-06), and then for it to return the next split date (1991-02-04) until such a point where the daily price date hits that...and so on.

So:

```
Date        Split_Date   Split_factor
2014-02-21  1998-07-06   0.333333015
2014-02-20  1998-07-06   0.333333015
2014-02-19  1998-07-06   0.333333015
...
1998-07-06  1998-07-06   0.333333015
1998-07-05  1991-02-04   0.970365703
1998-07-04  1991-02-04   0.970365703
...
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: MS-SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
select *
from continuousTable c
inner join splitTable s on s.fs_perm_sec_id = c.fs_perm_sec_id
where s.split_date = 
    (
    select max(s2.split_date)
    from splitTable s2
    where s2.fs_perm_sec_id = c.fs_perm_sec_id
    and s2.split_date <= c.date
    )
```

The inner join on splitTable limits the splitTable rows to theose with the same fs_perm_sec_id, while the where limits splitTable rows further to only those with a split_date which is the highest that is <= the Date on the continuous table.

The efficiency will depend on the indexes on the splitTable, and the number of rows in each. At a guess, it will help to have an index on splitTable of (fs_perm_sec_id, split_date) but you'll have to experiment and look at query plans to check that. (SSMS in SQL Server is very helpful with suggesting indexes that can help improve query times.)

Answer (score 0):

try a non-equijoin and then select the newest candidate based on split_date:

```
with crossdata as (
        select p.fs_perm_sec_id
             , p.[date]
             , p.p_price
             , s.p_split_factor
             , s.split_date
             , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.fs_perm_sec_id, p.[date] order by s.split_date desc) cand from #price p
          join #split s
            on p.[date] >= s.split_date
           and p.fs_perm_sec_id = s.fs_perm_sec_id
)
select fs_perm_sec_id
     , split_date
     , p_price
     , p_split_factor
  from crossdata
 where cand = 1
```